# I will do talking vs. I will talking

Tags: verbs, american-english, gerunds, future-tense

In the first episode of Big Bang Theory Leonard says "I will do talking". But as a learner i could not understand what is the difference between "talking" and "do talking". Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=big-bang-theory&episode=s01e01), he says "I'll do the talking."

Answer (score 2):

There are a few grammatical errors in the question, but I think what you're asking is the difference between "I will talk" and "I will do the talking".

1. **I will do the talking** (as Khan indicates, meaning I will do **all** the talking), applies to a situation in which a group of people are in a setting where speaking to someone in authority will likely be inevitable, but saying the wrong thing could cause a problem.

   The desire is to control the message; make sure the right things are said in the right way and nobody says something contradictory.

   "The talking" refers to that inevitable speaking.  So, "I will do the talking" means I'll be the one, and the only one, responsible for doing it.
2. **I will talk** could be used in a number of different ways, generally to inject order into a discussion or indicate a willingness to talk. For example:

   - It provides some order to the conversation so only one person is trying to talk at a time.  It announces that I'll talk next.
   - It can be an "ice breaker". You have a bunch of people in a setting, supposedly there to talk about something but nobody wants to go first.  So one person volunteers to go first and says, "I will talk".
   - It could indicate willingness to "cooperate".  For example, the police have a suspect and pressure them to confess or give up details about the crime.  The perpetrator would signal agreement to do that with "I will talk" (i.e., about the crime).

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I played around with the formatting. I had just wanted to bring to the forefront what I had perceived as a good answer. But if you don't like it, of course, please do not mind me and just roll it back to the way you had had it :). I had tried to stick to your style (with the bullets) as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'll just assume that you mean:

```
I'll do the talking.
```

The person saying this usually wants the other person/people to stay silent in a subsequent conversation/interaction.

Ex. Rob and Chad are smoking marijuana when they hear a knock at the door.

```
Chad: Oh fuck, its the cops.
Rob: Jesus, calm your tits, Chad.
Chad: I have a college scholarship, dude. I can't get this on my record.
Rob: Just sit down. I'll do the talking.
```

In the upcoming conversation with the police at the door, Rob indicates to Chad that he will take the lead in the conversation and only expects that Chad stays silent.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do  talking.

I'll talking.

Both of them are ungrammatical.

Regarding the former, the correct phrase is "do (all) the talking", not "do 
talking".  According to McMillan, when somebody do the talking, they deal with a difficult situation by talking or explaining things. For example:

When we get in to see him, you'd better let me do the talking.

As for the latter, the 'will' is a modal verb; it's always followed  by an infinitive without to.  For example: I'll talk.

Comment: "I'll do the talking" is definitely grammatical.  I think that might have just been a typo on your part, though?

Comment: @stangdon, Yes, it's a type. Thanks. I've edited my answer.